# How can I use rails- devise to sign up multiple users at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I am trying to figure out how to use Devise to do a '1-page' sign-up for a group.

Trying to make it as simple as possible.

I am trying to get teams of users signed up through 1 team leader.

So I send the team leader a link and they would go to 1 page that would have fields for their email address, perhaps password field(s) too.

They below I would have a grid, i.e. nested_attributes of rows for the emails of the users that the team leader is signing up.
I would want the users listed below the team leader to have, in their record, who the team leader is.

The problem is that all the uses I have had of Devise and all the examples I see are for doing things 'user by user' and not in this 'batch' fashion.

I don't need the final code written (though wouldn't object to any pseudo),  I am looking for advice on the process.

My though so far is to have two forms.  The top one in particular should be ajax based and should create the team leader user as soon as they leave the field.  What about all the users below.   I don't really want to ajaxify each row that has the users email so that it is calling a method that interacts with Devise - yuch.  I think that this should be a regular 'form' that gets submitted (perhaps with client-side validation for email@address.format) but I am still stuck on the right approach for registering the 'batch' of users this way.